# White screen in strapi admin panel

Tags: strapi

I have created admin panel in strapi. Some times in development and production
when i try to load any page it loads a white screen. Upon refreshing many times it loads the page.Below is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "pro-s",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.1",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@_sh/strapi-plugin-ckeditor": "^1.0.7",
    "@strapi/icons": "^1.7.3",
    "@strapi/plugin-graphql": "^4.1.8",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.4.3",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.4.3",
    "@strapi/provider-email-sendgrid": "^4.1.12",
    "@strapi/provider-upload-aws-s3": "^4.1.9",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.4.3",
    "chargebee": "^2.10.0",
    "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.11",
    "koa-static": "^5.0.0",
    "mime-types": "^2.1.35",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "pg": "^8.6.0",
    "pg-connection-string": "^2.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "sanitize-filename": "^1.6.3",
    "strapi-plugin-measurement-protocol": "^1.0.1",
    "strapi-provider-email-smtp": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "9b33cdcc-bad0-4fee-a674-da565a2a2b4c"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.19.1 <=18.x.x",
    "npm": "8.11.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Error in console

```
main.71cca37f.js:50 TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at propertyIsEnumerable (<anonymous>)
    at j1 (7098.8b467fed.chunk.js:1:441)
    at R (7098.8b467fed.chunk.js:341:24043)
    at ss (main.71cca37f.js:48:54759)
    at vc (main.71cca37f.js:48:64597)
    at h4 (main.71cca37f.js:52:10075)
    at bd (main.71cca37f.js:52:989)
    at l4 (main.71cca37f.js:52:917)
    at h0 (main.71cca37f.js:52:768)
    at U0 (main.71cca37f.js:50:11072)
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
R0 @ main.71cca37f.js:50
G.callback @ main.71cca37f.js:50
ud @ main.71cca37f.js:48
yc @ main.71cca37f.js:50
s4 @ main.71cca37f.js:52
f.unstable_runWithPriority @ main.71cca37f.js:84
Po @ main.71cca37f.js:48
Nl @ main.71cca37f.js:52
U0 @ main.71cca37f.js:50
(anonymous) @ main.71cca37f.js:48
f.unstable_runWithPriority @ main.71cca37f.js:84
Po @ main.71cca37f.js:48
x0 @ main.71cca37f.js:48
il @ main.71cca37f.js:48
Le @ main.71cca37f.js:52
Ju @ main.71cca37f.js:48
Show 1 more frame
Show less
main.71cca37f.js:50 TypeError: Qe is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at ge (4748.b84bcfda.chunk.js:1:383)
    at R (4748.b84bcfda.chunk.js:504:4342)
    at ss (main.71cca37f.js:48:54759)
    at vc (main.71cca37f.js:48:64597)
    at h4 (main.71cca37f.js:52:10075)
    at bd (main.71cca37f.js:52:989)
    at l4 (main.71cca37f.js:52:917)
    at h0 (main.71cca37f.js:52:768)
    at U0 (main.71cca37f.js:50:11072)
    at main.71cca37f.js:48:39565
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
R0 @ main.71cca37f.js:50
G.callback @ main.71cca37f.js:50
ud @ main.71cca37f.js:48
yc @ main.71cca37f.js:50
s4 @ main.71cca37f.js:52
f.unstable_runWithPriority @ main.71cca37f.js:84
Po @ main.71cca37f.js:48
Nl @ main.71cca37f.js:52
U0 @ main.71cca37f.js:50
(anonymous) @ main.71cca37f.js:48
f.unstable_runWithPriority @ main.71cca37f.js:84
Po @ main.71cca37f.js:48
x0 @ main.71cca37f.js:48
il @ main.71cca37f.js:48
Le @ main.71cca37f.js:52
Ju @ main.71cca37f.js:48
Show 1 more frame
Show less
main.71cca37f.js:50 TypeError: Qe is not a function or its return value is not iterable
    at ge (4748.b84bcfda.chunk.js:1:383)
    at R (4748.b84bcfda.chunk.js:504:1514)
    at ss (main.71cca37f.js:48:54759)
    at vc (main.71cca37f.js:48:64597)
    at h4 (main.71cca37f.js:52:10075)
    at bd (main.71cca37f.js:52:989)
    at l4 (main.71cca37f.js:52:917)
    at h0 (main.71cca37f.js:52:768)
    at U0 (main.71cca37f.js:50:11072)
    at main.71cca37f.js:48:39565
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
R0 @ main.71cca37f.js:50
G.callback @ main.71cca37f.js:50
ud @ main.71cca37f.js:48
yc @ main.71cca37f.js:50
s4 @ main.71cca37f.js:52
f.unstable_runWithPriority @ main.71cca37f.js:84
Po @ main.71cca37f.js:48
Nl @ main.71cca37f.js:52
U0 @ main.71cca37f.js:50
(anonymous) @ main.71cca37f.js:48
f.unstable_runWithPriority @ main.71cca37f.js:84
Po @ main.71cca37f.js:48
x0 @ main.71cca37f.js:48
il @ main.71cca37f.js:48
Le @ main.71cca37f.js:52
Ju @ main.71cca37f.js:48
Show 1 more frame
Show less
216main.71cca37f.js:50 TypeError: Property description must be an object: sc-kgwpUT mOrCs
    at defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at un (7909.4877546f.chunk.js:1:351)
    at ye (7909.4877546f.chunk.js:504:1387)
    at ss (main.71cca37f.js:48:54759)
    at vc (main.71cca37f.js:48:64597)
    at h4 (main.71cca37f.js:52:10075)
    at bd (main.71cca37f.js:52:989)
    at l4 (main.71cca37f.js:52:917)
    at h0 (main.71cca37f.js:52:768)
    at U0 (main.71cca37f.js:50:11072)
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
R0 @ main.71cca37f.js:50
G.callback @ main.71cca37f.js:50
ud @ main.71cca37f.js:48
yc @ main.71cca37f.js:50
s4 @ main.71cca37f.js:52
f.unstable_runWithPriority @ main.71cca37f.js:84
Po @ main.71cca37f.js:48
Nl @ main.71cca37f.js:52
U0 @ main.71cca37f.js:50
(anonymous) @ main.71cca37f.js:48
f.unstable_runWithPriority @ main.71cca37f.js:84
Po @ main.71cca37f.js:48
x0 @ main.71cca37f.js:48
il @ main.71cca37f.js:48
Le @ main.71cca37f.js:52
Ju @ main.71cca37f.js:48
Show 1 more frame
Show less
main.71cca37f.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at propertyIsEnumerable (<anonymous>)
    at j1 (7098.8b467fed.chunk.js:1:441)
    at R (7098.8b467fed.chunk.js:341:24043)
    at ss (main.71cca37f.js:48:54759)
    at vc (main.71cca37f.js:48:64597)
    at h4 (main.71cca37f.js:52:10075)
    at bd (main.71cca37f.js:52:989)
    at l4 (main.71cca37f.js:52:917)
    at h0 (main.71cca37f.js:52:768)
    at U0 (main.71cca37f.js:50:11072)
```